# How to instantiate a List<someType> that is null and is inside an object using reflection? OR instantiate an object of the type of the list

Tags: java, reflection

I have an object that I need to parse and initialize. All fields of this object that are null and set all their string fields to "". The problem is when one of the fields of the object is `List<someType>`. Then I need to create a new object of this type and call the method on it again.

The `field.getType()` gives me the interface list, so that I can't do `field.getType().newInstance()`;

I tried getting type of the list and tried to create an instance out of it, but this gives me exception :

```
Object obj1 = ((ParameterizedType) listType).getActualTypeArguments()[0].getClass().newInstance();
```

The complete code :

```
Field [] fields = segment.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
if (fields == null || fields.length < 0) {
    log.info("Field Array Null or Empty");
}
for (Field field : fields){
        if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(List.class)) {
            if ( field.get(segment) == null) {
                log.info("++++++++++++++++++++++++ list is null +++++++++++++++++ = " + field.getName().getClass().getName() + " list type " + field.getType());
                //field.set(segment, field.getType().newInstance());
                //field.set(segment, (List<Object>) field.getType().newInstance());
                List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

                Type listType = field.getGenericType();
                if (listType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                    Type elementType = ((ParameterizedType) listType).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
                    log.info("............ element type of list ............" + elementType);
                    Object obj1 = elementType.getClass().newInstance(); //HERE FAILS TO CREATE INSTANCE OF LIST TYPE
                    list.add(obj1);                            
                } 
                field.set(segment, list);
                for (Object obj : (List)field.get(segment)) {
                     log.info("++++++++++++++++++++++++ list segment +++++++++++++++++ = " + obj.toString());
                     populateUnusedFields(obj);
                }                       
          }
     }
 }
```

I need to create an object of the class specified as generic in the generic list.

Comment: The types are erased anyway, so why can't you just create a `new ArrayList<Object>()` and suppress the unchecked cast warning?

Comment: If the `newInstance()` call is failing with an access exception, it's probably because the parameterless constructor is not public. And that's probably because there is another constructor which you should be using instead. Without some kind of factory abstraction, there is no way to know the "correct" way to construct an object of an arbitrary type. If you just want an object of the type which may be arbitrarily malformed, you can use `Unsafe`, but I would strongly recommend against doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
Type elementType = ((ParameterizedType) listType).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

`elementType` refers to the generic type declared for the `List` field.
For example for a field `List<String>` `xxx`, the `Type` will be the `java.lang.String` `Class` instance.

And the problem is that then you do :

```
Object obj1 = elementType.getClass().newInstance(); //HERE FAILS TO CREATE INSTANCE OF LIST TYPE
```

But `elementType.getClass()` doesn't still return the `java.lang.String` Class. Instead of it returns the Class of `java.lang.String` Class that is just `Class`.

What you want is casting the Type to a Class to be able to use it then :

```
Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) elementType;
Object obj1 = clazz.newInstance();
```

Or better since `Class.newInstance()`  is deprecated :

```
Object obj1 = null;
try {
    obj1 = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    // handle the exception
}
```

Note that a `Type` is not always a `Class`, it may be other things. But in the actual case, it will be.

Comment: Awesome. ti worked. I got to work using  Class c= Class.forName(elementType.getTypeName(). but It is good to learn the way you did it. simpler